# Issue while using assertion in Robot Automation Framework with python library

Tags: python, robotframework

I am using Robot automation Framework with python library pyperclip and pyautogui and facing issue when using the assertion.

**Step1:** Open site in chrome browser(using demo html page)
[Web site Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJjWm.png)

**Step2:** I am coping the 1st sentence using pyautogui and pyperclip library and storing that value in variable(below is my .py file)

```
import pyautogui as pi
import pyperclip

def rendering():
pi.moveTo(444, 302)
pi.sleep(2)
pi.doubleClick(444, 302)
pi.doubleClick(444, 302)
pi.doubleClick(444, 302)
pi.sleep(2)
pi.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
test1 = pyperclip.paste()
# test1.replace(" ", "")
return test1
```

Step3: Running the file using robot framework

```
*** Variables ***
${browser}    chrome
${url5}       https://testsites.rbi.qa.forcepoint.com/english/
${english}      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

*** Test Cases ***
 Secure_Rendering_language_english
 [Documentation]     Test to check site is securly renduring in chinese 
  smiplified language
  [Tags]     localization      english
  open browser       ${URL5}       ${browser}
  maximize browser window
  Sleep    4
  ${result} =    rendering
  log to console    ${result}
  should be equal as strings       ${english}       ${result}
```

**Error:**
[Error screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJjWm.png)

**In the Error both the text are identical still it is giving me error that two test are not identical**

Comment: The text you copy from the webpage in the rendering function might have different whitespace. Look into what exactly it is copying.

Comment: is there any way we can figure out how to remove the white spaces between them or is there any way we can remove or trim those white spaces. I have tried split() and replace() method as well